# Handling special characters in c#

Tags: c#

In a C# console app, <del>I am using [stringbuilder to write data to a local file](https://github.com/cledwyn/OracleToCSVdotnetConsoleApp/blob/76843c3a53cf1bcc7508a7c0a992243e718cf489/Program.cs).</del>  It seems to be mishandling special characters

```
Muñoz
```

outputs to the file as

```
MuÃ±oz
```

at a bit of a loss how to manage that correctly.

Comment: string builders don't have the concept of encoding.

Comment: yes, I know I am using StringBuilder in conjunction with File.WriteAllText(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your C# code is correctly writing a UTF8 file, in which `ñ` is encoded as 3 bytes.

You're incorrectly *reading* the file as a different encoding which shows those bytes as three unwanted characters.
You need to read the file as UTF8.

Comment: Interesting.  I am outputing the file to .csv.  How do I specify how to read the file as UTF8?

Comment: That did it.  I changed my File.SaveToFile from File.WriteAllText(filename, sb.ToString()); to File.WriteAllText(filename, sb.ToString(),Encoding.UTF8);  Thanks a ton.  Muñoz, Peña, Bråten, et. all thank you as well.  :)